# Node: fs.watch() is too quick

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

Doing this in `Node 12.18.0` on `macOS 10.15.6 (Catalina)` ...

```
fs.watch('./stories/index.yaml', 'utf8', (eventType, fileName) => {
    let file = fs.readFileSync('./stories/index.yaml', 'utf8')    
    index = yaml.parse(file)
    console.log(file)
})
```

... will *almost* always result in `file` being `null` (after I save `index.yaml`, manually, in VSC).

However, if I set even a milisec of delay, it works fine:

```
fs.watch('./stories/index.yaml', 'utf8', (eventType, fileName) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
        let file = fs.readFileSync('./stories/index.yaml', 'utf8')    
        index = yaml.parse(file)
        console.log(file)
    }, 1)
})
```

Why does `file.watch()` call its callback before the file is ready to be read? Am I doing anything wrong? Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Does the file not exist before running the code?

Comment: @Gagan the file does exist, it's sitting in the same directory. But it doesn't even really matter, because this happens on every save.

Comment: Is this sample working, for me it works fine.  ```const fs = require('fs');
fs.watch('./test1.txt', 'utf8', (eventType, fileName) => {
  console.log(fs.readFileSync('./test1.txt', 'utf8'));
})```

Comment: @Gagan this is not working either for me. If you put "console.log('---');" after your console.log statement, then start hammering CMD+S (or CTRL+S), I see in the log that more often than not, there are more than one divider (--) between the printed contents of the file, indicating that there were callback occasions that the file was not ready.

Comment: Please provide your OS name and version also. May help users to understand your issue.

Comment: Thanks @Gagan, I added it on the top of the question.

Comment: Try to change the file from another software, when I changed the file from VScode the watch was called twice and sometimes the first was null as you said. But when I changed the file from notepad it was called once and from the 100 tries none of them was null. Maybe VScode does something with the directory  that makes watch fire to early.

Comment: Could you please log `eventType` parameter? Maybe this will reveal something about VSCode's operations over a file/directory